# Torch.nn has a specific activation function?

Tags: python, pytorch

My network has a output layer with Relu activation function, but I want the output is something like "Relu+1", that is I want the output is all bigger than 1 and has the same shape of Relu function.
How should I change my torch.nn network?
My code is like:

```
self.actor = nn.Sequential(
                     nn.Linear(state_dim, 256),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(256, 256),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(256, action_dim),
                     nn.ReLU()
)
```

Comment: You can add 1 to the output of the layer in `forward`, no? e.g., `x = x + 1` at the end of the forward propagation.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Actually he use `nn.Sequential`. The dumb SO edit system doesn't allow me to fix that.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen I'm not sure if using `nn.Sequential` matters here. They can do (in `forward` function): `x = self.actor(x); x = x + 1` and `x` then will indeed be offseted to be at least 1.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `self` is actually an `nn.Module` either

Comment: THANKS A LOT! In fact, I would choose the "THRESHOLD" activation funcion as my secondary choice, but it doesn't works very well. Because I am a kid in front of Pytorch and Thank you anyway for your sincere answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can think of.

1. Make `self.actor` an `nn.Module` object

```
class Actor(nn.Module):
    def __int__(self, state_dim, action_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(state_dim, 256)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(256, action_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = self.relu(x) + 1
        return x

class ......
    self.actor = Actor(state_dim, action_dim)
```

2. Make a `Module` class to do that and add it to the `self.actor`

```
class Add1(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return x + 1

class ......
    self.actor = nn.Sequential(
                     nn.Linear(state_dim, 256),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(256, 256),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     nn.Linear(256, action_dim),
                     nn.ReLU(),
                     Add1()
)
```

Comment: So cool! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! FORGIVE MY POOR ABOUT Pytorch.

Comment: @keqi Pease accept the answer to close the question if it works :)